# Error on running application on background

Tags: php

I have used the following code

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
$getdata=$this->input->post('textarea');
$arr = explode("\n",$getdata);
foreach ($arr as $a1){
    $count = $count+1;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
```

When I run above code in my local computer (WAMP Server 2.1 on windows Vista) it complete all task even I close browser. but when I upload to server it stop to work after processing 69 datas.

Comment: OOM? What is the error, anyway?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you fix up some grammar?

Comment: Is it your own server or a shared server? Some hosting companies kill PHP-scripts that are running too long.

Comment: @Nemoden It is just blank and stop to working

Comment: @edwin it is dedicated server.

Comment: So it is either stopped because all of the work is done or it fails with an error. Your error log is supposedly somewhere in `/var/log` directory (see your `php.ini` to find out whether logging to file and which file is `On`). Or you probably better to turn errors outputing placing `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beggining of your script.

Comment: Have you set time_limit in php.ini on the remote server? Does the script stops after exactly 30 or 60 seconds, then it is probably killed by some other (parent) process.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_time_limit(0);` to ignore [execution time limitation](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).
[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score -2):

do you mean?

```
echo count($arr);
```